# How can we simply surpress log error messages in pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

Consider you have a unit test written in `pytest`,
in which you check a state of some exception raised and caught within a function.

When an exception is caught, and error log message is written, which is fine - but less for the context of tests running, as it not clean and may cause confusion when tests are passing but an error log message appears.

Is there a simple way to suppress error messages from `pytest` perspective?

Comment: Can you add an example of what you mean when you say _"error messages"_? Do you mean log text that's being emitted by a `logger.error("...")` call in your code?

Comment: @damon: yes, exactly

Comment: @damon: Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging in pytest is captured by default -- meaning, the logs are not output to the log handlers when pytest is running.

This can be configured using [setting `log_cli` option](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/logging.html#live-logs). To prevent logs from being output to the console, [try setting `log_cli` to `False`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#confval-log_cli) in your pytest configuration file.

For example, if you're using `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
log_cli = False
```

You can further disable the display of `stdout`, `stderr`, and logs on failed tests completely by using the `--show-capture=no` option when you run `pytest` on the command line or by adding it to your `pytest.ini` file:

```
[pytest]
addopts=--show-capture=no
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the test using the command :

```
python -m pytest test_pytest_summary.py --tb=short
```

where, `-- tb=short` is the flag for shorter traceback format.

### **OR**

You can put `-- tb=short` in pytest.ini file :

```
[pytest]
addopts = -vs -ra --tb=short -p no:cacheprovider
```